# Laravel Carbon dates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have a date 15-08-2017 and I have a value 25.  If I add 25 to that date it should automatically add the number to the date and display the result as 09-09-2017.  How can I do that using Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$date = Carbon::parse('15-08-2017')->format('d-m-Y');
echo $date->addDays(25);
```

More details about Carbon can be found in the [documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
$dt = Carbon::create(2017, 8, 15, 0);
echo $dt->addDays(25);
```

**OR**

```
$dt = Carbon::parse('15-08-2017')->format('d-m-Y');
echo $dt->addDays(25);
```

Both work for me

And more details please follow this link [Carbon docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Its may be help for you !!!

Answer (score -2):

```
$mydate = '23-01-2016';
$daystosum = '2';
$datesum = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($mydate.' + '.$daystosum.' days'));
```